# PHP JWT compatible with Draft 11 of JSON Web Tokens

Tags: php, json, encryption, jwt

My PHP application is recieving JSON Web Tokens as per the 11th Draft for JWT. I was wondering if there was a PHP Class or Library capable of decoding JWTs signed (JWS) and encrypted (JWE)? I can only find one for Draft 6 which doesn't have the recent changes to encryption (from A128CBC+HS256 to A128CBC-HS256). https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token-11 - see this for details.

The issue im currently facing is the PHP JWT library im currently using warns of too many segments when attempting to decrypt the tokens im recieving. It's expecting 3 segments, but I receive 5.

Any help with this would be appreciated hugely!

Comment: The only thing I've found is https://github.com/nov/jose-php

Answer (score 1):

at Namshi we've developed our [own implementation of the JOSE/JWT/JWS](https://github.com/namshi/jose) spec.

I've written an [article](http://odino.org/securing-your-http-api-with-javascript-object-signing-and-encryption/) some time ago that serves as an addition to the [brief documentation](https://github.com/namshi/jose/blob/master/README.md): we've been using it for a few months now and we're pretty happy with the results.

Answer (score 0):

I have developped a PHP library to support JWT, JWS, JWE, JWK and JWA. This library is in active developpement and already offers a lot of signatures and encryption algorithms.
The documentation is still incomplete, but do not hesitate to contact me if you have any questions.

If you received 5 segments, it is a JWE object (encrypted). To decrypt it, you must have a private key (JWK object).

https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/JOSE